# Notifications template bug in TeamCity (BUILD_NUMBER)?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I've set up TeamCity to notify the whole team when a new internal release is ready. The email contains links to server folders where the distributive has been placed. The link pattern is quite simple, the only thing that's 'dynamic' is the lowest-level folder - it's name matches the version number.

The folder is generated by MsBuild using TeamCity's "build.number" property. All is good with it, its name contains only what has been specified in the pattern (e.g. 1.0.0.0). But the strange thing is that {BUILD_NUMBER} in notifications template returns **#**1.0.0.0 (with the # sign).

So the email ends up with bad links.
Has anyone noticed this? Is there a fix?

Comment: I am not sure this is a correct place to inform about a bug in TeamCity. Have you tried with vendor's support? http://www.jetbrains.com/support/teamcity/index.html

Comment: Well, the reason is that I'm not sure it's a bug. So maybe community has already seen this issue or knows what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported bug seems to have got a fix in version 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else asked essentially the same question on the [JetBrains TeamCity blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2007/09/25/customizing-teamcity-notifiers-templates/), as well as on the [Developer Community forums](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5192729#5192729).

It appears the community has already seen this issue, but there doesn't seem to be a easy fix or  workaround:)